# Weird OS X Terminal Bug: Cursor won't go back to end of line after backtracking

Tags: macos, terminal, cursor

I have an interesting problem: when I type something in the terminal as follows:

```
~ me$ hello<cursor>
```

and backtrack:

```
~ me$ he<cursor>llo
```

and then try to return to the end to continue typing, perhaps after fixing an error, I get stuck before the last character:

```
~ me$ hell<cursor stuck here>o
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I've tried looking around and changing the terminal to xterm instead of xterm-256-color, etc. but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I am using the arrow keys to move back and forth.

Comment: Have you ever modified your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files?

Comment: No, but I have a modified ~/.inputrc file, which was copied from here to make some improvements: https://github.com/whiteinge/dotfiles/blob/master/.inputrc

Comment: Can't figure out why but it's it that causes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've been beating my head over this for a few days now and I've finally got it. It turns out the solution is simple: **update bash to 4.3**. The default bash on Macs (even Yosemite) is 3.2.

Install Homebrew with

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then do

```
brew install bash
```

then change your default shell path (in Terminal Preferences) to

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

and that's it. Check your bash version with

```
bash --version
```

and as an added bonus, you can get mode indicators!

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'
```

and it will show a `+` for Insert mode and `:` for Command mode.

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't have enough reps to add this as a comment, I'll have to ask this in the **answer** section (even though it's discouraged).

First, how are you trying to move the cursor? Are you using the **arrow keys** or are you using the basic **vi** commands? i.e. have you tried: <kbd>$</kbd> ?

Anyway, it would be helpful if you gave more detail as to the specific keys you're pressing in the example you provided (i.e. whether arrows or shortcuts and, if the latter, which specific key combinations).