# How do I move the cursor past the end of the line in Insert mode when using vi-style line editing on bash?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, vi, cursor

In all that follows, the `^` indicates the position of the cursor.

I'm using bash on Terminal on OS X Yosemite and I'd like to use vi-style line editing:

```
prompt$ set -o vi
                 ^
```

By default it starts in vi Insert mode, so I can immediately type

```
prompt$ hello
             ^
```

Now let's say I use the left arrow key <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>H</kbd> to move left:

```
prompt$ hello
            ^
```

Now I can no longer move to the *right* of the `o` in `hello` using either <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd>:

```
prompt$ hello  # I can't move here anymore!
             ^
```

If I am to append something, I have to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

This does not happen in emacs mode (`set -o emacs`) or on certain Linux machines (ssh'd into SLC 6.6 with bash 4.1, or natively on my friend's (I think Arch) with bash 4.3). In all of these, <kbd>←</kbd> then <kbd>→</kbd> takes me to the end of the line where I can keep typing; on my Mac terminal I cannot unless I leave Insert mode.

This also does not happen with vim on my Mac; vim lets me move past end of lines with arrow keys in Insert mode. It's just readline vi mode.

I tried updating my bash (with Homebrew) from 3.2 to 4.3; that did not fix it.

I tried removing my .bash_profile and using an unmodified Terminal; that did not fix it. (I have some aliases and prompt modifiers in my .bash_profile.)

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/how-do-i-quickly-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-in-bash-in-vi-mode), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/358760/osx-terminal-moving-to-end-of-line), and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126732/weird-os-x-terminal-bug-cursor-wont-go-back-to-end-of-line-after-backtracking). They don't have answers.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Edit:
On a Linux system where things work as I would like it to, the TERM variable gives

```
prompt$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

The contents of `/etc/inputrc` are

```
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

# Completed names which are symbolic links to
# directories have a slash appended.
set mark-symlinked-directories on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
# commented out keymappings for pgup/pgdown to reach begin/end of history
#"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
#"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
```

Comment: Can you post the value of the `TERM` environment variable as well as the contents of `/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc` (if it exists) from one of the systems where this behaviour works as you want it to (just the non-commented lines as the file is possibly quite large)?

Comment: @mjturner I edited my post. I don't have a `.inputrc` in my home directory. I posted the contents of `/etc/inputrc`, it was pretty short, but I don't know if this particular `/etc/inputrc` is the one you want, since the Linux machine on which I work serves many users.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion of exactly the same issue on the [bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2007-02/msg00000.html), albeit on a DEC Alpha. If you read the full thread, Chet Ramey suggests that a termcap entry (terminfo on a Mac) could be sending an Esc, causing problems with vi mode.

Comment: Okay, it actually just randomly started working. I guess my bash update took some time to "take". So I guess the solution is to update bash from 3.2 to 4.3 on Macs.

@mjturner Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution is simple: **update bash to 4.3**. The default bash on Macs (even Yosemite) is 3.2. (My question above says I did update and it didn't work, but I think it took a while for it to "take.")

Install Homebrew with

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then do

```
brew install bash
```

then change your default shell path (in Terminal Preferences) to

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

and that's it. Check your bash version with

```
bash --version
```

and as an added bonus, you can get mode indicators!

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'
```

and it will show a `+` for Insert mode and `:` for Command mode.

Comment: Ideally, you should also add your new version of bash to `/etc/shells` and then change your shell using `chsh` (or *System Preferences* > *Accounts*).